# Visual Studio Copy all Output (Postbuild Event)

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to create a postbuild event in visual studio (2008 in this case) to copy the output to a specific directory. I want to copy the entire contents of the output folder (because I'm pulling in references assemblies using the copy local option) and the directory I want to copy to I need to pull from the registry.

I've not really used the postbuild stuff before so I'm wondering if anyone can help me out, basically I'm not sure if I can do a copy all DLL's/PDB's or whether I need to define them manually. If I have to define them manually then I don't want to be doing repeated registry lookups.

The reg lookup I'm using is along the lines of :

> REG QUERY "HKLM\Software\SR\BIA\2010"
>   /v Location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write a batch file and perfom the query + copy in it, call batch file in postbuild event